# wlan0 not showing up ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, drivers

I type iwconfig, but wlan0 is not showing up, which means that I cant make use of the wifi connection. Is there any way to solve this? I searched on the internet, tried everything.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 07 Dec 2014 00:53 CET +0100

Booted last: 07 Dec 2014 00:24 CET +0100

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-40-generic #69-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 13 17:53:56 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e091] (rev 13)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1102]
    Kernel driver in use: alx

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:003e] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1525]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1770:ff00  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1532:0034 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

ath9k                 164164  0 
ath9k_common           13551  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              453856  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    28698  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
rtl8187                64909  0 
msi_wmi                13354  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 msi_wmi
ath3k                  13318  0 
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
mac80211              626557  2 ath9k,rtl8187
cfg80211              484040  4 ath,ath9k,mac80211,rtl8187
eeprom_93cx6           13344  1 rtl8187
wmi                    19177  3 msi_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
bluetooth             391136  12 bnep,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:19 

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #######################

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            alx
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HUSHAK2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=HUSHAK2 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=HUSHAK2 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Amsterdam (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[ath9k]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     DF02272C2FA4678C49046E5
depends:        ath9k_hw,mac80211,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-40-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        35:72:8C:DB:88:AA:70:FD:D3:AC:D1:53:A3:7B:51:31:92:A4:7F:D8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)

[ath9k_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     696B00A6C59713EC0966997
depends:        ath,ath9k_hw
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-40-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        35:72:8C:DB:88:AA:70:FD:D3:AC:D1:53:A3:7B:51:31:92:A4:7F:D8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath9k_hw]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     4809F3842A0542CD6B556D3
depends:        ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-40-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        35:72:8C:DB:88:AA:70:FD:D3:AC:D1:53:A3:7B:51:31:92:A4:7F:D8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     88A67C5359B02C5A710AFCF
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-40-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        35:72:8C:DB:88:AA:70:FD:D3:AC:D1:53:A3:7B:51:31:92:A4:7F:D8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtl8187]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/rtl8187.ko
license:        GPL
description:    RTL8187/RTL8187B USB wireless driver
author:         Larry Finger <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Hin-Tak Leung <htl10@users.sourceforge.net>
author:         Herton Ronaldo Krzesinski <herton@mandriva.com.br>
author:         Andrea Merello <andrea.merello@gmail.com>
author:         Michael Wu <flamingice@sourmilk.net>
srcversion:     A707FEC6B464A70F7A04C69
depends:        mac80211,eeprom_93cx6,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-40-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        35:72:8C:DB:88:AA:70:FD:D3:AC:D1:53:A3:7B:51:31:92:A4:7F:D8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath3k]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko
firmware:       ath3k-1.fw
license:        GPL
version:        1.0
description:    Atheros AR30xx firmware driver
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     661F5D1CDD236CFF7BE3FA5
depends:        bluetooth
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-40-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        35:72:8C:DB:88:AA:70:FD:D3:AC:D1:53:A3:7B:51:31:92:A4:7F:D8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-40-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     123C230E7AC85A31E4CA28B
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-40-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        35:72:8C:DB:88:AA:70:FD:D3:AC:D1:53:A3:7B:51:31:92:A4:7F:D8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-40-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     C2478077E22138832B71659
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-40-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        35:72:8C:DB:88:AA:70:FD:D3:AC:D1:53:A3:7B:51:31:92:A4:7F:D8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath9k]
blink: 0
bt_ant_diversity: 0
btcoex_enable: 0
nohwcrypt: 0
ps_enable: 0

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x1969:0xe091 (alx)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8187)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[ 1271.629279] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address> by local choice (reason=2)
[ 1271.682093] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address>
[ 1271.734834] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[ 1271.737556] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1271.741333] wlan0: associate with <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[ 1271.744295] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=4)
[ 1271.745156] wlan0: associated
[ 1366.347460] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address> by local choice (reason=3)
[ 1372.282283] ieee80211 phy5: hwaddr <MAC address>, RTL8187vB (default) V1 + rtl8225z2, rfkill mask 2
[ 1372.290396] rtl8187: Customer ID is 0x00
[ 1372.290736] rtl8187: wireless switch is on
[ 1374.148683] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[ 1377.612480] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address>
[ 1377.817495] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[ 1377.820307] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1377.824186] wlan0: associate with <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[ 1377.827171] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=4)
[ 1377.827871] wlan0: associated
[ 1377.827903] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[ 1377.849661] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address> by local choice (reason=2)
[ 1377.900723] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address>
[ 1377.953493] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[ 1377.955846] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1377.956077] wlan0: associate with <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[ 1377.958957] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=4)
[ 1377.959739] wlan0: associated
[ 1781.561606] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address> by local choice (reason=3)

########## wireless info END ############
```

I will be really gratefull if someone would know the solution. Laptop without wifi  is terrible :(

My laptop is a msi gs60. I heard that there were some wifi problems on ubuntu with these laptops. I visited every page on www but nothing solved my problem

I also searched for additional drivers from software & updates. But there are no additional drivers available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 Wireless not working: no network interface](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661424/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-not-working-no-network-interface)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no support for your 168c:003e device. Please see this recent thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2248919 I suggest you register and add to this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1383184 "Atheros Qualcomm Killer N1525 Wireless-AC [168c:003e] not supported"

Comment: Well, I guess I won't be buying an Alienware laptop then - their entire (2015) line uses this wireless card! Sure glad I found this before I made my purchase...