# Ubuntu 14.04 Wireless not working: no network interface. Atheros [168c:003e] device

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, atheros

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS after installing windows 10 in my new VN7-571G and the wireless is not working.
It never had: even during the installation it was not recognized.

I run a script to gather the data , which is [here](http://www.pasteall.org/60457/text).

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` output

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:003e] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0804]
```

The OS behaves like it has no wifi card. I do not see wifi settings in network settings

I'm not a linux power user, so I do not know what to do to solve the issue.
What should I do to make it work?

Comment: I believe his device is covered in `ath10k_pci`.

Comment: There is only 003c.

Comment: Just one thing. The upload speed through the wireless card is much smaller (50 mbps) than the upload speed through the ethernet card (220 mbps)...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This device is supported in Ubuntu 15.10 with the latest updates.

- You can get it work **in Ubuntu 14.04** by installing kernel 4.2 and the updated firmware. Run in terminal:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
  wget https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.157_all.deb
  sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.157_all.deb
  ```
- **In Ubuntu 15.10 and later** you only need to install the firmware:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
  ```

In both cases, reboot afterwards.

Comment: Replying to you using the wifi connection now. Great work. Noticed the touchpad scroll is not working now. Can it be related?

Comment: That was the solution I needed to make backports into dkms deb files, you have to copy the backports after running `make deconfig-wifi` or whatever individual module you want

Comment: Many, many thanks for solving problem with my lenovo e31-70 laptop in 3 mins :)

Comment: @Pilot6 They released the fixed firmware. Could you reply to http://askubuntu.com/questions/697448/ubuntu-14-04-install-firmare-released-for-ath10k-pci ?

Comment: It is not only a firmware issue. This is also a kernel module. You'd better asked a new question.

Comment: Uninstall the module by `sudo dpkg -r ath10k-dkms` and follow the updated answer.

Comment: The current link to deb file gives 404

Comment: @Makers_F Fixed. But it is obviously will be updated from time to time there.

Comment: Is there a webpage which specifies the urls?

Comment: @Makers_F Sure http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?lang=ru&suite=xenial&keywords=linux-firmware

Comment: Here the english version http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?lang=en&suite=xenial&keywords=linux-firmware

Comment: It has chosen the language automatically, I guess. I didn't notice that ;-)

Comment: I am running 14.04.4 LTS .This solution makes my computer 10 times slower.So I removed them from my machine.Again I can not see any wireless sign anymore in my machine

Comment: For me the Wi-fi had always worked earlier, and all of a sudden the 'Enable W-ifi' disappeared from the menu. I followed the above steps in the answer for Ubuntu 14.04 and my Wi-fi has started working again.  Although one thing that I would like to bring to notice - While installing the 'linux-generic-lts-wily', I did get a Bad Status Error, but that was all, nothing has broken so far. I have been able to boot as usual and my Wi-Fi works. So @Pilot6 Thanks a Lot!