# Ubuntu 14.04 Install Firmare released for ath10k_pci

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, atheros, firmware

Follow up to [Ubuntu 14.04 Wireless not working: no network interface. Atheros [168c:003e] device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661424/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-not-working-no-network-interface-atheros-168c003e-dev)

The devs have released the firmware ([as noted in the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1383184/comments/337))

Now, I have the firmware installed under the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/661434/408196) instructions.

How do I remove that firmware and start using the official one (so that I have something more tested and I'll get updates/bugfixes in the future)?

```
$ dmesg | grep qca6174
[   14.926504] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca6174 hw2.1 (0x05010000, 0x003405ff, 168c:003e:11ad:0804 fallback) fw rome-hw2.1-v211-michalk api 2 htt 3.0 wmi 4 cal otp max_sta 32
```

Comment: Edit to add result of `dmesg | grep qca6174`  I think you likely have the latest firmware

Comment: I don't really know how linux works for this matter, but how can I have an updated firmware if I installed it manually? BTW edited as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have installed an **official** `linux-firmware` package from an official Ubuntu repository. But you installed a version for Ubuntu 15.10.

It did not install automatically, because the Atheros new firmware is available only for Ubuntu 15.10 (wily) at the moment.

Version numbers for `linux-firmware` for different Ubuntu releases differ. That is why this firmware package will never be replaced by anything in Ubuntu 14.04.

But I do not see any reason to worry about that.

If you really want to bother about that, you can track if that new Atheros firmware gets into Ubuntu 14.04 `linux-firmware` package and when it does (if ever) you can remove that package and install a native one for 14.04.

But I can't imagine why that may be ever needed.

Comment: Since 14.04 is LTS, won't it be backported? Sometimes on linux the connection just randomly drops, while on windows I've never experienced something like that. So I think it might be something on the firmware. But yeah, it's working and that's ok

Comment: It probably will be included in 14.02. But you do not understand what firmware is. It is a closed source binary file provided by the chip manufacturer. It can't be "backported" anywhere. It can be just included in a package to install to `/lib/firmware` directory. On Windows you use the same firmware as in Linux. There may be some problem in the new driver. But it is quite another issue. It will probably improved with kernel updates.

Comment: Fair enough! I though it was open source (like the VGA drivers, I can have either the open or the closed source ones)

Comment: I'm still having the dropped problem. The network managers says I'm connected (it shows the connected icon)but I can't even resolve the names of the sites, and ping 8.8.8.8 just drops every packet (but it doesn't raise an error like when you are not connected to the net). This only happens on some routers (so maybe it's frequency related?).
http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/all/linux-firmware/filelist and http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/linux-firmware/filelist show the same firmware .bin for ath10k
Might it be that removing the 15.10 package and using the trusty one will solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since you installed from an Ubuntu deb file you don't have to do anything.  When Ubuntu finds a newer version of linux-firmware it will be installed when you do updates