# Qualcomm Atheros Device 003e (rev 32) not working

Tags: wireless

There is no wireless device available in my network manager.
After doing as suggested in another thread regarding this issue, following these steps didn't work

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
wget https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.156_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.156_all.deb

Linux sunny 4.2.0-30-generic #36~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 26 18:49:23 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

.

```
Linux sunny 4.2.0-30-generic #36~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 26 18:49:23 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:15b8] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8672]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:86e0]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

This isn't a dupe. The dupe link does not fix the problem I am having. 
I also looked over here [Ubuntu 14.04 Install Firmare released for ath10k_pci](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697448/ubuntu-14-04-install-firmare-released-for-ath10k-pci) and I'm still at square one

Comment: You didn't boot with the Linux kernel v4.2 backported from Ubuntu Wily (see `Linux sunny 3.19.0-32-generic`).

Comment: Have you tried booting using the backported kernel as explained in the linked duplicate?

Comment: `Linux sunny 4.2.0-30-generic #36~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 26 18:49:23 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

still doesn't work

Comment: This is not a dupe.

Comment: It would be beneficial to [edit] your question and add what you've tried already, the output to `rfkill list` and  `lspci -v -s 02:00.0` instead of just saying "It's not a dupe".  Also have [a look here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/697448/ubuntu-14-04-install-firmare-released-for-ath10k-pci) in the mean time.  **;-)**

Comment: `rfkill list 
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
`
 `lspci -v -s 02:00.0
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 86e0
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
 Memory at df000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci`

Comment: I looked at http://askubuntu.com/questions/697448/ubuntu-14-04-install-firmare-released-for-ath10k-pci, still at square one

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: For a full picture, please [run the network diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.