# WLAN interface not detectetd on Acer Aspire VN7-791

Tags: wireless, drivers, acer, interface

I have tested several Ubuntu distributions (Ubuntu, Mint) on my Laptop (Acer Aspire VN7-791), but on none of them the WLAN interface (Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4) could be detected. I already know about the Acer Hotkeys issue, but I dont't think this is the cause because the other hotkeys are working correctly (e.g. deactivating the mousepad). So I have no idea why the interface can not be used.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0804]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1692] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:091d]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wireless adapter is supported in Ubuntu 15.10 after running

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You need to be connected to internet by wire to get the updates.

If you like an LTS version of Ubuntu, you can get the adapter work there using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/661434/167850)