# I can't find wireless interface ""wlan0"" ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers

I just installed ubuntu 14.04.3 (LTS). My laptop can dual-boot Windows 10 & Ubuntu. But I have a problem of using wireless network. When I open the terminal and type

> Code:
>
> > iwconfig

returns the following

> > eth0 no wireless extensions.
> >
> > lo no wireless extensions.

I can't find

### wlan0 IEEE 802.11 blah blah blah...

Also when I type

> Code:
>
> > sudo wpa_cli

returns the following

[image]

As far as I know, in normal circumstances, wireless interface information should be seen. Just like below picture:

[image]

I think my ubuntu can't detect wireless LAN Card.(But when I use windows, My PC can connect to wifi and can use the web)

I need your help. Thank you. Before complete question, I show my PC information.

---

> > First OS : Windows 10
> >
> > Second OS : Ubuntu 14.04.3 (LTS) Desktop Version
> >
> > > **windows and ubuntu dual-boot**
> >
> > Ubuntu Kernel Version : 4.3.3-040303-generic
> >
> > My Network Adapter
> >
> > > > Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4 Wireless Network Adapter
> > > >
> > > > Realtek PCle GBE Family Controller

.......................................................................

when I type

> Code:
>
> > ifconfig

returns the following

> > eth0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:f5:aa:d7:f2:1d
> >               inet addr:165.132.117.69  Bcast:165.132.119.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
> >               inet6 addr: fe80::26f5:aaff:fed7:f21d/64 Scope:Link
> >               UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
> >               RX packets:315020 errors:0 dropped:396 overruns:0 frame:0
> >               TX packets:157677 errors:7 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
> >               collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
> >               RX bytes:323556810 (323.5 MB)  TX bytes:14659107 (14.6 MB)
> >
> > lo      Link encap:Local Loopback
> >               inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
> >               inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
> >               UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
> >               RX packets:4694 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
> >               TX packets:4694 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
> >               collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
> >               RX bytes:459292 (459.2 KB)  TX bytes:459292 (459.2 KB)

Comment: What does show `lspci | grep Atheros`?

Comment: returns,
Qualcomm Atheros Device 003e (rev 20)

Comment: What does ifconfig return? Did you try starting wpa_supplicant before running wpa_cli?

Comment: Did you try [that solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/661434/266507)?

Comment: @박주현 please [edit] the ifconfig results into your original question instead of posting them as comments

Comment: @Hi-Angel thank you your comment~ I am trying now.. please wait for minutes, Thank you~!

Comment: @ApolloLV Could you tell me what I type in terminal using wpa_supplicant?? I am a linux new-bie, so please teach me specifically what I type... Thank you~

Comment: You should probably stick to the network manager instead of wpa_supplicant. It can be used as a replacement, but it will be really tedious to get running, especially for a newbie.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Thank you~ Thank you~~ My Ubuntu finally detecting wireless APs. Thank you for helping me..