# Ubuntu 14.04LTS does not recognize Network and Ethernet controllers

Tags: 14.04, drivers

Here are specs on Network and Ethernet controllers:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: Qualcomm Atheros 
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros 
   physical id: 0 
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0 
   version: 32 
   width: 64 bits 
   clock: 33MHz 
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list 
   configuration: latency=0 
   resources: memory:dc200000-dc3fffff 
*-network UNCLAIMED 
   description: Ethernet controller 
   product: Qualcomm Atheros 
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros 
   physical id: 0 
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0 
   version: 10 
   width: 64 bits 
   clock: 33MHz 
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list 
   configuration: latency=0 
   resources: memory:dc500000-dc53ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

Other System info is:

Model:     MSI GT 72 Dominator

Memory:    15.6 GiB

Processor: IntelCore i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz x 8

Graphics:  Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 256 bits)

OS type:   64-bit

Disk:      634.1 GB

I really appreciate any help with this - I am not very experienced so need answer styled for dummies

Thanks very much,
JP

HERE IS INFO REQUESTED BY Pilot6:

u

```
ser@User-Ubuntu:~$ lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net' 

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:003e] (rev 32) 

    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1535] 
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:5249] (rev 01) 
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1143] 
-- 
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [1969:e0a1] (rev 10) 

Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1143] 

3e:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:010f] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'` terminal command.

Comment: Regarding the wireless see http://askubuntu.com/a/661434/167850

Comment: Thanks for the link on wireless, but still don't have Ethernet/ network access to be able to utilize the suggested fix - JP

Comment: You can download files using another computer and install without a network connection.

Comment: Pilot 6 - What if I just install fresh 15.04 or 16.04 - do these have functional Network drivers? Thanks,

Comment: 16.04 probably has the wireless driver and firmware.

Comment: @Pilot6 - Used "Moshi" UBS Ethernet adaptor to establish Ethernet connection, installed all updates to 14.04, and followed your askubuntu.com/a/661434/167850 instructions, but still no wireless or ethernet?