# Touchpad and wireless adapter not recoginsed Acer Aspire V3-372-53UE

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, touchpad, acer

I have installed the offical Ubuntu 14.04 OS. After booting I have realized that my touchpad and wifi are not working. I connected usb mouse and usb wifi adapter and they are both working so I think I am having troubles with drivers. Can anyone help? Btw everything is working on Windows 10.

Thanks in advance!

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:104c]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0807]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
```

Comment: Please edit question to include results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 Wireless not working: no network interface. Atheros \[168c:003e\] device](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661424/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-not-working-no-network-interface-atheros-168c003e-dev)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why are you having problems with the touchpad, but the thing with the wifi is very normal for the newest pc on the market,  so for that problem you can try this :
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper

that's gonna install the wifi drivers of windows on Ubuntu or something like that, btw I'm not a english speaker (?) so my redaction have a lot of mistakes , but I want to help you 
saludos :)

Comment: -1 if you dont know the cause then you should omit such answers

Comment: actually my answer solve part of his problem