# Install Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4 drivers without Internet access

Tags: networking, drivers, atheros

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and having problems with my wifi card. As it reads in the title, i dont have any internet access on my Laptop and cannot install any packages via api-get. I tried every suggestion i found in the forums but none wants to work. I cannot install the windows driver either, because i cannot install wine.
Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 Wireless not working: no network interface. Atheros \[168c:003e\] device](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661424/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-not-working-no-network-interface-atheros-168c003e-dev): just download these on another computer, copy them to a USB stick and install them on your computer, or buy an Ethernet cable, plug it into your computer and the router! (which is the easiest solution to your problem)

Comment: P.S. Windows drivers don't work under wine: wine is for applications only.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Android phone with wifi-data, you can enable data-share (tethering) and connect it to your Computer.(use this guide, for usb tethering) https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2812516?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried USB tethering but it dooes not work with my Phone ( even with app support )